# CSS - vertical align text and button

Tags: html, css

I have a jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/hjq6ay60/12/

Super simple, I always forget how to do this.

I have text floated left and a button floated right.

I just need to centre them both vertically - I'm sure you can do this with adding padding to the text.

```
.block{
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 400px;

    &-top{
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    &-bottom{
        float: right;
         vertical-align: middle;
        &__button{
            border: 1px solid grey;  
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Floated elements cannot be centred.

Comment: How can I have the elements on either side without floating them. I need text on the left and the button on the right can them to be vertically centered.

Comment: Okay I got it solved.

Comment: @PraveenKumar it can, but with using `margin` or `top/bottom/left/right` if the element has `position: relative` or `position: absolute`

Comment: @C0dekid.php Added Answer.

Comment: You have my upvote :-) @PraveenKumar

Comment: @ttmt Does my approach work for you?

Answer (score 2):

why don't you use `display:table` and `display:table-cell` ?? see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hjq6ay60/18/)

```
.block {
   display:table;
}
.block-bottom,.block-top {
   display table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
.block-bottom {
   width: 50px;
}
```

and remove `float:left` and `float:right` from  `.block-bottom .block-top`

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain with a code. :)

Answer (score 1):

We could make use of `position` and `translateY` this way:

```css
.block {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;               // Add here
  &-top {
    position: absolute;             // Add here
    top: 50%;                       // Add here
    left: 5px;                      // Add here
    right: 65px;                    // Add here
    transform: translateY(-50%);    // Add here
    p {
      margin: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

**Preview**

[image]

**One Line: https://jsfiddle.net/xpgszmvn/**
**Multi Line: https://jsfiddle.net/zqxvwv8L/**

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox can do that for you, for free. Plus you get the added bonus of getting rid of the floats.

**[Example Here](https://jsfiddle.net/hjq6ay60/19/)**

```
.block{
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 400px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; /* Magic! */

    &-top{
      flex: 1; /* Stretch this item all the way */
               /* By default, items take only as much as they need */
    }

    &-bottom{
        /* No need for floats or display: */
        &__button{
            border: 1px solid grey;  
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! :) You are here! :)

Answer (score 0):

use `height` and `line-height` at equal values for example

```
button{
  height:30px;
  line-height:30px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Always text will come in center

For two line text

```
 button{
   width:50px;
   height:auto;
   padding:10px;
}
```

This will create button with height depending on text

Comment: If the text exceeds the line, this would be a problem. Even I thought of this.

Comment: Yes I could have two line of text

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Surely work for you.

```
.block {
    display: table
}

.block-top {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.block-bottom {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```